# Hover change the position of the hover of the item below it

Tags: css, html, hover

This is the code of the images

```
<div id="content">
<div id="boyset">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Baby Boy Set</legend>
    <ul>
    <li><p>2-Piece Shirt & Pant</p>
    <a href="2-Piece Shirt & Pant.html"><img src="images/11.jpg"/></a><br/><p>$12.00</p></li>
    <li><p>2-Piece Top & Jeans</p><a href="2-Piece Top & Jeans.html"><img src="images/12.jpg"/></a><br/><p>$26.00</p></li>
    <li><p>3-Piece</p><a href="3-Piece.html"><img src="images/13.jpg"/></a><br/><p>$15.00</p></li>
     <li><p>2-Piece Top & Legging</p><a href="2-Piece Top & Legging.html"><img src="images/14.jpg"/></a><br/><p>$24.00</p></li>
     <li><p>2-Piece Top & Legging</p><a href="2-Piece Top & Legging.html"><img src="images/15.jpg"/></a><br/><p>$24.00</p></li>
     <li><p>2-Piece Top & Legging</p><a href="2-Piece Top & Legging.html"><img src="images/16.jpg"/></a><br/><p>$24.00</p></li> 
     <li><p>2-Piece Top & Legging</p><a href="2-Piece Top & Legging.html"><img src="images/17.jpg"/></a><br/><p>$24.00</p></li>
     <li><p>2-Piece Top & Legging</p><a href="2-Piece Top & Legging.html"><img src="images/18.jpg"/></a><br/><p>$24.00</p></li>   </ul>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS code

```
#content{
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    height:1065px;
    width:1200px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:5px solid #404A7F;
    border-radius:10px;}


#boyset fieldset{
    width:1100px;
    height:980px;
    border:3px solid #404A7F;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    font-family:Century Gothic;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#404A7f;}

#boyset ul{
    list-style-type:none;}

#boyset ul li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:200px;
    width:250px;
    height:300px;}

#boyset li img{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;}

#boyset p{
    width:250px;
    text-align:center;}

#boyset p:nth-child(1){
    color:#003;}

#boyset ul li:hover{
    width:250px;
    height:400px;
    border:3px dashed #404A7f;
    background-image:url(images/add_cart.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom;}
```

When the mouse come on the image on the first row the image under it change its position.I want it to make the hover properly without changing the position of the image below it.

Answer (score 0):

You use different margin and border in

```
#boyset ul li:hover{
width:250px;
height:400px;
border:3px dashed #404A7f;
background-image:url(images/add_cart.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:bottom;}
```

and

```
#boyset ul li{
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
margin-bottom:200px;
width:250px;
height:300px;}
```

try using the same value for margin and border (for border use a color not visible where used without hover).

Inspect you code with a tool in browser like firebugs or equivalent and try change the value..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone I have found the solution for my code I changed the CSS code to

```
#content{
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    height:1065px;
    width:1200px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:5px solid #404A7F;
    border-radius:10px;}


#boyset fieldset{
    width:1100px;
    height:980px;
    border:3px solid #404A7F;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    padding-right:40px;
    font-family:Century Gothic;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#404A7f;}

#boyset ul{
    list-style-type:none;}

#boyset ul li{
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    width:250px;
    height:420px;
    border:2px solid;}


#boyset li img{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;}

#boyset p{
    width:250px;
    text-align:center;}

#boyset p:nth-child(1){
    color:#003;}

#boyset ul li:hover{
    width:250px;
    height:418px;
    border:3px dashed #404A7f;
    background-image:url(images/add_cart.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom;}
```

Now its all works fine :D